# minimap not available anymore in gedit

Tags: gnome, 20.04, gedit

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04. Everything works fine.  I wanted to customize gedit, but I was surprised that the minimap option is not available anymore.

[image]

How to get it back?

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04  
Gnome Version: 3.36.2  
Windowing System: X11
gedit version: 3.36.2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On 18.04 LTS with Gedit 3.28.1 this option was named as "Display overview map", was controlled by corresponding GSettings/Dconf setting:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor display-overview-map true
```

but in 20.04 LTS this option does not exist on source-code level.

This was indicated in commit [from 2019-11-19](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gedit/-/commit/26899e0ba7c1390c098b61fc7a901d700c4e745c) with main idea to "simplify the gedit code".
So this functionality was removed by upstream.

---

You may want to find a workaround in [the bugreport](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gedit/-/issues/285) at GNOME GitLab - install user-defined [plugin](https://github.com/johnfactotum/gedit-restore-minimap):

```
sudo apt-get install git
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins/
cd ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins/
git clone https://github.com/johnfactotum/gedit-restore-minimap.git restore-minimap
```

Then open Gedit *Preferences*, go to *Plugins*, and check *Restore Minimap* checkbox.

Comment: Works with Gedit 3.36.2